# Power BI Chart Formatting Issue

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

The chart legend doesnt fit in the vizualization. Therefore, pbi just adds a button.
Example: Button circled in red.

[image]

There is a way to remove this button and add a breakline ? So it can just keep going below.
Thx.

Comment: I know i can put the legend on the right or left side of the chart and it will show everything. But that doesnt resolve the issue i'm having. Do you guys know any other way to get around this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. If you want more control over chart elements, I recommend using Deneb.

Comment: Do you know where i can find any good content about Deneb ?

Comment: Sure - here you go. https://deneb-viz.github.io/

Comment: If you have any trouble, post on StackOverflow and I can help.